# How can momentum scrolling be disabled in iOS 13 / Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, webkit, ios13

iOS 13 made momentum scrolling the default for overflow: auto elements (used to need -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch). However, this causes problems in some cases, and I need to manually disable this.

I've tried setting the property to auto, none, and various other things, to no avail.

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: none
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto

Neither stops momentum scrolling.

I'd expect there to be a way to manually disable it.

Comment: I hope it's just a bug that will get fixed in the following release... `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` worked on previous iOS versions

Comment: okey, I see they changed the behavior of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` in Safari 13, but there is no mention about the property `auto`, or how to disable the acceleration...
[link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes)